# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). I'm only studying and don't know what to do

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors, xcode14

https://github.com/RomchikNaKaife/laba3_4sem/blob/main/laba3_4sem/Programm/main.cpp

There's a link for my programm file. Working in XCode 14 on mac.
I've tried to ask GPTs. They're useless or maybe I am useless :)

There's log:

```
  Shape2D::GetArea() const, referenced from:
      vtable for Square in main.o
  Shape2D::operator==(Shape2D const&) const, referenced from:
      vtable for Square in main.o
  Shape2D::operator>(Shape2D const&) const, referenced from:
      vtable for Square in main.o
  Shape2D::operator<(Shape2D const&) const, referenced from:
      vtable for Square in main.o
  Shape3D::GetVolume() const, referenced from:
      vtable for TriangularPyramid in main.o
      vtable for Cylinder in main.o
      vtable for Sphere in main.o
  Shape3D::operator==(Shape3D const&) const, referenced from:
      vtable for TriangularPyramid in main.o
      vtable for Cylinder in main.o
      vtable for Sphere in main.o
  Shape3D::operator>(Shape3D const&) const, referenced from:
      vtable for TriangularPyramid in main.o
      vtable for Cylinder in main.o
      vtable for Sphere in main.o
  Shape3D::operator<(Shape3D const&) const, referenced from:
      vtable for TriangularPyramid in main.o
      vtable for Cylinder in main.o
      vtable for Sphere in main.o
  typeinfo for Shape2D, referenced from:
      typeinfo for Square in main.o
      typeinfo for Triangle in main.o
      typeinfo for Circle in main.o
  typeinfo for Shape3D, referenced from:
      typeinfo for TriangularPyramid in main.o
      typeinfo for Cylinder in main.o
      typeinfo for Sphere in main.o
  vtable for Shape2D, referenced from:
      Shape2D::Shape2D() in main.o
      Shape2D::Shape2D(Shape2D const&) in main.o
  vtable for Shape3D, referenced from:
      Shape3D::Shape3D() in main.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Lets take the first error which is about `Shape2D::GetArea`. The linker says it's undefined, can you find the definition in your code? I couldn't. I guess you meant to declare it as pure virtual, i.e. `virtual float GetArea() const = 0;`. Pure virtual functions do not need to be defined. You did this with `CalculateArea` but for some reason you did not do it with `GetArea`, `operator==` etc etc.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow is a library of questions and answers, and for that library to be useful important information like the code that caused the problem must be available to future askers so that they can assess whether or not your question also applies to them. You cannot count on links because they rot, the contents change, or they get blocked by firewalls and network problems. Everything required to understand the question MUST be in the question.

Comment: Where is your `Shape2D.cpp` file? It seems you just did not implement a few functions that you declared in your header files. If you don't plan to implement these and they already inherit from their parent remove them from the header.

Comment: Firewalls are preventing me from following you link.  Please post an [mcve].